# Leaving a data array (Font) in FLASH - PROGMEM in AVR GCC

Tags: string, memory, avr, avr-gcc, winavr

Ahhh, PROGMEM, pointers, pointers to pointers, addresses of pointers... My head boggles.

I have a data array for the font in question

```
const uint8_t dejaVuSans9ptBitmaps[] = 
{
    /* @0 ' ' (5 pixels wide) */
    0x00, /*          */
    0x00, /*          */
...
```

to which I have added PROGMEM

```
const uint8_t dejaVuSans9ptBitmaps[] PROGMEM =
```

This is referenced in another structure like so;

```
const FONT_INFO dejaVuSans9ptFontInfo = {
   13,
   ' ',
   '~',
   dejaVuSans9ptDescriptors, 
   dejaVuSans9ptBitmaps,
};
```

The structure is defined as;

```
typedef struct {
   const uint8_t           height;       
   const uint8_t           startChar;    
   const uint8_t           endChar;      
   const FONT_CHAR_INFO*   charInfo;    
   const uint8_t*          data;         
} FONT_INFO;
```

Am I correct in assuming this needs to change to;

```
typedef struct {
   const uint8_t           height;       
   const uint8_t           startChar;    
   const uint8_t           endChar;      
   const FONT_CHAR_INFO*   charInfo;    
   const PGM_P             data;         
} FONT_INFO;
```

When I do so, it complains that

```
warning: pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness
```

For this particular line in the FONT_INFO variable;

```
const FONT_INFO dejaVuSans9ptFontInfo = {
    13,
    ' ',
    '~',
    dejaVuSans9ptDescriptors, 
--> dejaVuSans9ptBitmaps, <--
};
```

It is then drawn using the function;

```
void drawString(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t color, const FONT_INFO *fontInfo, char *str) {
    ...
    drawCharBitmap(currentX, y, color, &fontInfo->data[charOffset], charWidth, fontInfo->height);
    ...
```

Which finally draws the glyph;

```
void drawCharBitmap(const uint16_t xPixel, const uint16_t yPixel, uint16_t color, const uint8_t *glyph, uint8_t cols, uint8_t rows) {
   ...
      if (glyph[indexIntoGlyph] & (0X80)) drawPixel(currentX, currentY, color);
   ...
```

I am in over my head :/ Can anyone give me some direction? I have spent hours trying to use PGM_P, and pgm_read_byte etc to no avail - I always get garbage on the screen.

Save me!

Comment: Have you tried reviewing the documentation at http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html ?

Comment: @Jeff I certainly did! I think it was more the pointers and address of pointers that through me. I didnt know when to tell the compiler to read from pgmspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I understand what is going on here.

First, `const uint8_t* data` is a pointer to the data stored in PROGMEM.

In the `function void drawString(uint16_t x, uint16_t y, uint16_t color, const FONT_INFO *fontInfo, char *str)` we pass a pointer to `fontInfo`.

To continue, the following is important to understand;

```
fontInfo.data
(*ptr_to_fontInfo).data
ptr_to_fontInfo->data
```

are all the same. So `ptr_to_fontInfo->data` returns the data (not address)

Then using the `&` operator, we pass the 'address of' this data to the next function

```
drawCharBitmap(currentX, y, color, 
  &fontInfo->data[charOffset], charWidth, fontInfo->height)
```

This address is stored in the declared pointer variable `unint8_t *glyph` here;

```
void drawCharBitmap(const uint16_t xPixel, const uint16_t yPixel, 
  uint16_t color, const uint8_t *glyph, uint8_t cols, uint8_t rows)
```

Keeping this in mind;

```
int *ptr;
int a;

ptr = &a;
```

Then glyph now points to the same address as `fontInfo->data[charOffset]`.

The next thing to know is;

> a[b] in C is just a fancy way for writing *(a + b)

So glyph being a pointer, when used like this `glyph[indexIntoGlyph]`, it is the same as `*(glyph + indexIntoGlyph)`, and the dereferencing operator `*` means we get the data at that address.

From there, we can use the pgm rules as wex described;

> If the variable is in PROGMEM, you use pgm_read_byte() as a
>   replacement for the dereference operator *. For "normal" variables in
>   RAM you can always write *(&a) instead of just a to return the value
>   of the variable a; so to return a 8-bit wide variable from progmem you
>   write pgm_read_byte(&x).

Hope this explanation is correct and helps people (newbies like me!) understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I got some great support over at AVRfreaks.net, and thought I'd post the answer here for future reference by this community. Thanks 'wek'!

'wek' identified that based on the information I gave, that I needed to send multiple bytes starting from `&fontInfo->data[charOffset]` in `drawCharBitmap()`.

> If the variable is in PROGMEM, you use `pgm_read_byte()` as a
>   replacement for the dereference operator `*`. For "normal" variables
>   in RAM you can always write `*(&a)` instead of just a to return the
>   value of the variable `a`; so to return a 8-bit wide variable from
>   progmem you write `pgm_read_byte(&x)`.
>
> Now recall that `a[b]` in C is just a fancy way for writing `*(a + b)`
>   (where `a` is a pointer pointing to the first member of the array,
>   thus rules of pointer arithmetics apply). So in `drawCharBitmap` you
>   can change `glyph[indexIntoGlyph]` either into
>   `pgm_read_byte(&(glyph[indexIntoGlyph]))`, or `pgm_read_byte(glyph +
>   indexIntoGlyph)`.

I'm still trying to understand the links here, but it was such a great answer it deserved to be put on here. Thanks to all who took the time to look at this.